# Send user to friend's profile within canvas app via automated URL in emails?

Tags: email, facebook-canvas

Question from a product management perspective at a company which will offer a complete UI of our product within our Facebook canvas app.

The desired functionality of a feature would be:

1. Registered user receives email suggesting friends to recommend our service to.
2. Email contains generated URL to our Facebook canvas app.
3. When clicked and opened, canvas app lands on page with information about suggested friend.

Is it possible to automate a URL that would trigger this?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass information in to you canvas app using the app_data parameter in the URL. The passed app_data is then made available as part of signed_request. You can find more at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

As an example, you could use the following URL

```
http://apps.facebook.com/mycanvasapp?app_data=some_app_data
```

The app_data variable of signed_request would then contain the string

```
some_app_data
```

If you need to pass something complex though app_data, I believe the most common method is to pass it as a JSON formatted string (see http://www.json.org/ for more on JSON).